# WSDL Endpoint example throwing errors in Mule

Tags: wsdl, mule, esb

Posting here is always my last resort, but I'm going crazy here. I'm a Mule ESB beginner. I've been trying to do some simple examples to get me on the right track.
But I've encountered a problem with one of the examples I've seen on the mule website... 
http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/WSDL+Connectors

I'm trying to set up a generic WSDL endpoint, which invokes a web service without generating a client.

The WSDL I'm trying to access...
   http://www.webservicex.net/CurrencyConvertor.asmx?WSDL&method=ConversionRate

The problem is, I keep getting the following error

```
[ERROR] IOException during exec() of compiler "javac". Check your path environment variable.
ERROR 2013-04-19 09:27:07,920 [[soap].soapFlow1.stage1.02] org.apache.cxf.endpoint.dynamic.DynamicClientFactory: Could not compile java files for http://www.webservicex.net/CurrencyConvertor.asmx?WSDL&method=ConversionRate?wsdl.
ERROR 2013-04-19 09:27:07,934 [[soap].soapFlow1.stage1.02] org.mule.exception.DefaultMessagingExceptionStrategy: 
********************************************************************************
Message               : Unable to create JAXBContext for generated packages: Provider com.sun.xml.bind.v2.ContextFactory could not be instantiated: javax.xml.bind.JAXBException: "net.webservicex" doesnt contain ObjectFactory.class or jaxb.index (java.lang.IllegalStateException)
Code                  : MULE_ERROR--2
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Exception stack is:
1. "net.webservicex" doesnt contain ObjectFactory.class or jaxb.index (javax.xml.bind.JAXBException)
  com.sun.xml.bind.v2.ContextFactory:183 (http://java.sun.com/j2ee/sdk_1.3/techdocs/api/javax/xml/bind/JAXBException.html)
2. Provider com.sun.xml.bind.v2.ContextFactory could not be instantiated: javax.xml.bind.JAXBException: "net.webservicex" doesnt contain ObjectFactory.class or jaxb.index (javax.xml.bind.JAXBException)
  javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder:-1 (http://java.sun.com/j2ee/sdk_1.3/techdocs/api/javax/xml/bind/JAXBException.html)
3. Unable to create JAXBContext for generated packages: Provider com.sun.xml.bind.v2.ContextFactory could not be instantiated: javax.xml.bind.JAXBException: "net.webservicex" doesnt contain ObjectFactory.class or jaxb.index (java.lang.IllegalStateException)
  org.apache.cxf.endpoint.dynamic.DynamicClientFactory:363 (null)
4. Unable to create JAXBContext for generated packages: Provider com.sun.xml.bind.v2.ContextFactory could not be instantiated: javax.xml.bind.JAXBException: "net.webservicex" doesnt contain ObjectFactory.class or jaxb.index (java.lang.IllegalStateException) (org.mule.api.DefaultMuleException)
  org.mule.module.cxf.builder.AbstractOutboundMessageProcessorBuilder:96 (http://www.mulesoft.org/docs/site/current3/apidocs/org/mule/api/DefaultMuleException.html)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Root Exception stack trace:
javax.xml.bind.JAXBException: "net.webservicex" doesnt contain ObjectFactory.class or jaxb.index
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.ContextFactory.createContext(ContextFactory.java:183)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    + 3 more (set debug level logging or '-Dmule.verbose.exceptions=true' for everything)
********************************************************************************
```

And yes, I've hunted around the internet for hours looking for a solution.

Things I've done to try fix the problem.

- Make sure the javac path is set in the environment variables.
  (%JAVA_HOME%\bin)
- Make sure that mule studio has the correct path to JRE

I know it's a simple problem, but I need to figure it out to tackle a larger project that I have in mind.
If anyone could shed some light on a solution this problem, then I'd be extremely grateful.

Thanks :)

Other info:

- Using Java 1.7
- Using MuleStudio 3.4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, after trying and failing at many different solutions, I've figured it out.
I've seen a lot of people asking the same question as me, with very few solutions.

Here is mine...
The JRE was incorrect.
My java directory consisted of..
 [image]

And Mule studio was using the folder jre7

So I changed it to use the JRE in the directory jdk1.7.0_17/jre

Ran it again and.. **OMG it worked!!**
Here is how to do it in mule studio/eclipse...
Right Click on your Project --> Properties --> Java Build Path --> Libraries Tab 
--> Click JRE System Library --> Press Edit --> Click Alternate JRE --> Click Installed JREs.. 
--> Then Add the JRE from the correct directory like I stated above.

Hope this helps anyone with the same problem! :)